# Apply class to neighbor div when div gets class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` containing all my content, and then I have a div containing pop-up windows. So basically something like this:

```
<div class="content">
    Some content
</div>

<div class="popup-wrapper">
    Popup content
</div>
```

Then at some point a class is added to the `popup-wrapper` due to some button click, that in Angular would look something like:

```
<button (click)="popup = !popup">Click me</button>

<div class="popup-wrapper" [ngClass]="popup ? 'is-active' : ''">
    Popup content
</div>
```

My question is: Are there some way (CSS wise. JS would probably also do if no other alternative is available) that when `popup-wrapper` has the class `is-active` I can also target `content` as well ?

The issue for me not just putting the same JS into the `content` div, i.e. `[ngClass]="popup ? 'is-active' : ''"` is because there are several instances that can activate a popup, and other popup wrappers as well. So if I were to do this I would have to go through every page that has this kind of `popup-wrapper`, and paste similar code into every `content` div, but with different state names.

So I just thought it would be much easier, if I could target the `content` div whenever the `popup-wrapper` div had the `is-active` class.

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, you'll need something like that:

```js
function anyName () {
  let x = document.getElementByClassName('is-active');
  if (x === true) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Depending on what ever you want to do next, you can either go for an identifier like your div's className ('content') or you try to target it by its position, like 'previousElementSibling'